Mount name by id on df
We installed a new UBUNTU 20.04 and config a few partitions.
All of the partitions are the some in the /etc/fstab.
When I run "df" command I see on all partition some thing like:
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-home     20G  217M   19G   2% /home

But only one partiton (/usr) look like:
/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-hEP1VraqQedO22sj1RLilQeauRIKF3UB3cOFAf157FG3TwCPl4w4OfDc0k6onulU   20G  3.6G   15G  20% /usr

in the fstab they both look the same:
/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-hEP1VraqQedO22sj1RLilQeauRIKF3UBUrAq6P2m2iVMKgvmTnEimmpRu5eQ85a4 /home ext4 defaults 0 1

/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-hEP1VraqQedO22sj1RLilQeauRIKF3UB3cOFAf157FG3TwCPl4w4OfDc0k6onulU /usr ext4 defaults 0 1

I can't understand why its showing with the uuid instead with the /dev/mapper like all others.
